# Are child soroban (abacus) classes worth doing?

Tags: education

I'm considering enrolling my five year old child in a weekly soroban course after school ('soroban' is the Japanese word for abacus).

They're quite expensive ($30 a lesson) but the companies running them swear that children will manage to learn arithmetic sooner and eventually perform the calculations mentally at very fast speed. This seems very useful for daily life, let alone when solving math problems in school.

But what do mathematicians actually think about this?

Comment: This is not mathematics.  It belongs on parenting.se

Comment: I recommend against. Too much mechanical work, not enough actual thinking.

Comment: Best ask this on [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) or perhaps on [MathEducation.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), but not here. This site is for mathematics.

Comment: The companies' claims sound like nonsense, to me. Ask them for references to rigorous scientific studies that support their claims. Seems to me that the best way to learn arithmetic is to do arithmetic, and not on an abacus.

Comment: Personally, I'm skeptical of how effective this would be. And I don't think being fast at mental arithmetic is all that helpful for a mathematician. I'd guess the child would be better off either using that time to do something fun or else learning to play an instrument or working on reading or doing actual math or something.

Comment: Most of the mathematically inclined would teach themselves how to use an abacus in an afternoon because their knowledge of math allows them to see how ridiculously simple an abacus is.

Answer (score 6):

This excerpt from the book *Surely, You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!* might be useful. Richard Feynman is a Nobel Prize winner and one of the greatest physicists of the 20th century. In this excerpt, he tells the story of when he met an abacus expert who "doesn't know numbers".

> A Japanese man came into the restaurant. I had seen him before,
>   wandering around; he was trying to sell abacuses. He started to talk
>   to the waiters, and challenged them: He said he could add numbers
>   faster than any of them could do.
>
> The waiters didn't want to lose face, so they said, "Yeah, yeah. Why
>   don't you go over and challenge the customer over there?"
>
> The man came over. I protested, "But I don't speak Portuguese well!"
>
> The waiters laughed. "The numbers are easy," they said.
>
> They brought me a paper and pencil.
>
> The man asked a waiter to call out some numbers to add. He beat me
>   hollow, because while I was writing the numbers down, he was already
>   adding them as he went along.
>
> I suggested that the waiter write down two identical lists of numbers
>   and hand them to us at the same time. It didn't make much difference.
>   He still beat me by quite a bit.
>
> However, the man got a little bit excited: he wanted to prove himself
>   some more. "Multiplicação!" he said.
>
> Somebody wrote down a problem. He beat me again, but not by much,
>   because I'm pretty good at products.
>
> The man then made a mistake: he proposed we go on to division. What he
>   didn't realize was, the harder the problem, the better chance I had.
>
> We both did a long division problem. It was a tie.
>
> The bothered the hell out of the Japanese man, because he was
>   apparently well trained on the abacus, and here he was almost beaten
>   by this customer in a restaurant.
>
> "Raios cubicos!" he says with a vengeance. Cube roots! He wants to do
>   cube roots by arithmetic. It's hard to find a more difficult
>   fundamental problem in arithmetic. It must have been his topnotch
>   exercise in abacus-land.
>
> He writes down a number on some paper— any old number— and I still
>   remember it: 1729.03. He starts working on it, mumbling and grumbling:
>   "Mmmmmmagmmmmbrrr"— he's working like a demon! He's poring away, doing
>   this cube root.
>
> Meanwhile I'm just sitting there.
>
> One of the waiters says, "What are you doing?".
>
> I point to my head. "Thinking!" I say. I write down 12 on the paper.
>   After a little while I've got 12.002.
>
> The man with the abacus wipes the sweat off his forehead: "Twelve!" he
>   says.
>
> "Oh, no!" I say. "More digits! More digits!" I know that in taking a
>   cube root by arithmetic, each new digit is even more work that the one
>   before. It's a hard job.
>
> He buries himself again, grunting "Rrrrgrrrrmmmmmm ...," while I add
>   on two more digits. He finally lifts his head to say, "12.01!"
>
> The waiter are all excited and happy. They tell the man, "Look! He
>   does it only by thinking, and you need an abacus! He's got more
>   digits!"
>
> He was completely washed out, and left, humiliated. The waiters
>   congratulated each other.
>
> How did the customer beat the abacus?
>
> The number was 1729.03. I happened to know that a cubic foot contains
>   1728 cubic inches, so the answer is a tiny bit more than 12. The
>   excess, 1.03 is only one part in nearly 2000, and I had learned in
>   calculus that for small fractions, the cube root's excess is one-third
>   of the number's excess. So all I had to do is find the fraction
>   1/1728, and multiply by 4 (divide by 3 and multiply by 12). So I was
>   able to pull out a whole lot of digits that way.
>
> A few weeks later, the man came into the cocktail lounge of the hotel
>   I was staying at. He recognized me and came over. "Tell me," he said,
>   "how were you able to do that cube-root problem so fast?"
>
> I started to explain that it was an approximate method, and had to do
>   with the percentage of error. "Suppose you had given me 28. Now the
>   cube root of 27 is 3 ..."
>
> He picks up his abacus: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz— "Oh yes," he says.
>
> I realized something: he doesn't know numbers. With the abacus, you
>   don't have to memorize a lot of arithmetic combinations; all you have
>   to do is to learn to push the little beads up and down. You don't have
>   to memorize 9+7=16; you just know that when you add 9, you push a
>   ten's bead up and pull a one's bead down. So we're slower at basic
>   arithmetic, but we know numbers.
>
> Furthermore, the whole idea of an approximate method was beyond him,
>   even though a cubic root often cannot be computed exactly by any
>   method. So I never could teach him how I did cube roots or explain how
>   lucky I was that he happened to choose 1729.03.

Answer (score -1):

It might be very useful at a young age, but as an adult there is no benefit of calculating at a fast speed. It doesn't teach you how to think.

Take computer science classes instead,you'll actually there be learning something of benefit and how to rack your mind to come up with a solution. This is not to mention the benefits that are accompanied with knowing how to build apps or websites..